How to create or insert data into a table that has no unique values using 2 different tables which also has no unique valus?
I have 3 tables.

Pin Code Master
Pin code temp
City temp

in pin code columns are
entry id - number
picode - number
state -  number
district - number
pin code temp is same as master
city temp
entry id - number
city name - string
state - number
district - number
state name - string
example data = pin code temp
32899, 343031, 29, 122
example data = city temp
6604, A Vellalapatti, 31, 666, Tamil Nadu
my problem is in some condition there are multiple entries available in city table with state and district.
now to fill my master table how to actually figure out the query to select the accurate data and fill my master table.
I tried to get the city name using state and district. which gave multiple results. but my master table must have only one result per state. I know i have to use FIU dabase to get the actual data but the same issue in their list. multiple cities with same state and district.

Please [edit] the question and provide a [MRE] with: the CREATE TABLE statements for your tables (including constraints); the INSERT statements for your sample data that replicates the issue (i.e. if you have multiple entries in pin_code_temp with the same state then your sample data should also have multiple entries with the same state); an English explanation of the problem that describes how you would ignore duplicates when generating the master data; YOUR attempt at a solution; the issues/errors with your solution; and the expected output for the sample data.

You have tagged the question with MySQL and Oracle, they are two different RDBMS with different syntaxes. Which one are you using?

I have multiple database. And same application is deployed on both. So that's why I tagged both. So in any db you can give a solution. It'll help.

You state:

pin code temp is same as master

and ask

how to actually figure out the query to select the accurate data and fill my master table

Ignore the city table and use only the pin_code_temp data to populate pin_code_master.
For example, if you want to insert all the rows from pin_code_temp into pin_code_master that have new primary key values then:
INSERT INTO pin_code_master (id, picode, state, district)
SELECT id, picode, state, district
FROM   pin_code_temp t
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
         FROM   pin_code_master m
         WHERE  t.id = m.id       -- Compare primary key columns
                                  -- If you have different primary/unique keys then
                                  -- change the filter and compare those columns.
       )

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE city (
  id        NUMERIC(10) PRIMARY KEY,
  city_name VARCHAR(50),
  state     NUMERIC(10),
  district  NUMERIC(10)
);

CREATE TABLE pin_code_master (
  id        NUMERIC(10) PRIMARY KEY,
  picode    NUMERIC(10),
  state     NUMERIC(10),
  district  NUMERIC(10)
);

CREATE TABLE pin_code_temp (
  id        NUMERIC(10) PRIMARY KEY,
  picode    NUMERIC(10),
  state     NUMERIC(10),
  district  NUMERIC(10)
);

INSERT INTO pin_code_master (id, picode, state, district)
SELECT 1, 1, 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 3, 2, 2 FROM DUAL

INSERT INTO pin_code_temp (id, picode, state, district)
SELECT 1, 1, 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, 1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 1, 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 3, 2, 2 FROM DUAL

Then, after the INSERT, pin_code_master contains:



ID
PICODE
STATE
DISTRICT




1
1
1
1


4
3
2
2


2
2
1
2


3
1
2
1



Oracle fiddle MySQL fiddle

Actually my problem is I don't have an primary key. But I tried your way and created a temp table. Now I had multiple results. And I used your query to fill the new temp table. And when I tried to find the city using this state and district I got a lot of single city results. I added those in master. Now the only remaining results are where I have multiple cities with same state and district. For now I'll be creating a mapping to manually select the city on frontend. Thanks for the main issue.
